# Automapper ProjectTo access parent from children

Tags: c#, automapper

Since ProjectTo [doesn't support](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#supported-mapping-options) `BeforeMap`, how can I pass the `parent` object to a `children` collection? Here is the code:

```
void Main()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(c =>
    {
        c.AddProfile<Prof>();
    });

    myDbContext.Profiles
        .ProjectTo<ProfileDto>()
        .Dump(); // Linqpad Extension

}

public class Prof : Profile
{
    public Prof()
    {
        CreateMap<ProfileEntity, ProfileDto>();
        CreateMap<UserEntity, UserDto>();
    }
}

public class ProfileDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserDto> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
}
```

I just want to fill the "ProfileName" property.

Comment: If you have User.Profile, you can map from that, otherwise you can [pass parameters](http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization).

Comment: So your `UserEntity` doesn't have `Profile` property (if you use EF for example - there is usually such navigation property)?

Comment: It does @Evk but if I have a scenario without referente to parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoMapper mapping configuration works on a single (source, target) level. I see no way to pass the parent to the child source configuration. Of course you can use full projection (LINQ `Select`) like in the other answer, but if the object being mapped contains a lot of properties, this will lead to a lot of redundant code even if they conventionally match by name.

One way that comes into mind is to use intermediate projection to pair the parent with the child:

```
class Prof : Profile
{
    public Prof()
    {
        CreateMap<ProfileEntity, ProfileDto>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Users, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
                src.Users.Select(u => new { User = u, Profile = src })));
    }
}
```

Now the AutoMapper [Flattening](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) feature will automatically map `source.Profile.Name` to `target.ProfileName`. The problem is that the main properties (from `User`) will not be mapped because they are not prefixed with `User` (e.g. `UserName`) in the target object. We can solve that by a custom [Naming Convention](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conventions.html). Add the following to a new code file in your project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions;
using AutoMapper.Internal;

namespace AutoMapper.Configuration.Conventions
{
    public class NameMatchMember : IChildMemberConfiguration
    {
        public bool MapDestinationPropertyToSource(ProfileMap options, TypeDetails sourceType, Type destType, Type destMemberType, string nameToSearch, LinkedList<MemberInfo> resolvers, IMemberConfiguration parent)
        {
            foreach (var memberInfo in sourceType.AllMembers)
            {
                if (!destType.Name.StartsWith(memberInfo.Name)) continue;
                resolvers.AddLast(memberInfo);
                var memberType = options.CreateTypeDetails(ReflectionHelper.GetMemberType(memberInfo));
                if (parent.MapDestinationPropertyToSource(options, memberType, destType, destMemberType, nameToSearch, resolvers))
                    return true;
                resolvers.RemoveLast();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}

namespace AutoMapper
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IMemberConfiguration AddNameMatchMemberConvention(this IProfileExpression target) =>
            target.AddMemberConfiguration().AddNameMatchMemberConvention();

        public static IMemberConfiguration AddNameMatchMemberConvention(this IMemberConfiguration target) =>
            target.AddMember<NameMatchMember>();
    }
}
```

The first class implements the custom convention. For each target name not mapped by other conventions, it tries to map it to a property of the source being a prefix of the target type name (e.g. `User` -> `UserDto`).

The second is just a convenient way to add it to the configuration. It could be applied at configuration or profile level, but in order to have effect on anonymous types, it has to be done on configuration level.

Now all you need is to apply it to your configuration:

```
Mapper.Initialize(c =>
{
    c.AddNameMatchMemberConvention();
    c.AddProfile(new Prof());
});
```

and this in combination with the above profile configuration will be enough to perform the desired mapping.